# Getting current location of a device with python

Tags: python, location

I am trying the following code that fetches data using API but didn't work, the error is

> **"key error ['city']"**. any solution ?

code:

```
import requests
import json

send_url = "http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"
geo_req = requests.get(send_url)
geo_json = json.loads(geo_req.text)
city = geo_json['city']
```

Comment: Is it contains `city` as key in your json data by printing `geo_json`

Comment: yeah,it is by default from the API,

Comment: Can you share the link so i can try with that api

Comment: https://ipinfo.io/

Answer (score 1):

following code will work:

```
import requests
import json

send_url = 'https://ipinfo.io?token=your_API_KEY'
geo_req = requests.get(send_url)
geo_json = json.loads(geo_req.text)
city = geo_json['city']
```